# Passing value between Javascript and ASP.NET C# not working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, hiddenfield

While making a website I bumped into a problem. Because I dynamicaly create a "Detail" Button I need to make use of a Hidden Value to see "On Load" wether the button has been clicked.

Wegpage + Jquery part:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <link href="css/assortiment.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function detailKlik()
        {
            var hid = $('#<%=hd.ClientID %>');
            hid.val("true");
        }
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hd" runat="server" Value="abc"/>
...
```

Whenever I press the dynamicaly generated button I can see that the javascript runs correctly. [I can see the original value in the element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7V2u.png).

[I can even see the "Value" value is changing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxlqo.png)

But when I debug in my c# code the value of the HiddenField is just back to the original.

Thank you :)

Comment: I'm not completely clear on your issue, but I don't think you can manipulate server-side (C#) code from client-side (Javascript/jQuery) code.

Comment: Have you looked at what the browser is sending to the ASP.NET page using F12 tools? Is the updated value being sent to the server?

Comment: @DaveB When I use the F12 tools in Chrome and I view the elements I can see the value has changed to true

Comment: @B.ClayShannon I'm just trying to manipulate an element in HTML code. In C# I'm trying to get this value through the same element. Odd thing is that the value in HTML code is changing... but when I request the value in C# it's not changed. 

I noticed that the value always is the same as the starter value...

Comment: @JasperCallens Check the Network tab in F12 tools and inspect what is being sent to the server. You are looking for the Request Body if this is a HTTP POST operation. Trying to figure out if the changed value is being sent to the server.

Comment: @DaveB wow, discovering new tools :D. I can see it sent "ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$hd:true" after I Click the button...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. Because I tried to access the Object's value in the method `protected void Page_Init(...)` I always got the default value.
When I access the value in for example `Page Load` I see the correct value.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  After the 2-day waiting period is completed, consider marking your own answer as 'Accepted'.